# Esscher transform (extension)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

The Esscher-transform is a well know tool in the financial section.

Given a Levy-process $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ under $P$. Let be $u$ be real such that $\phi_{t}(u)=\log\left(E\left[\exp(uX_t)\right]\right)$ is finite. We have with levy-properties $\phi_{t}(u)=t\phi_{1}(u)$.

We know that the Esscher-transform

$$
Z_{t}=e^{uX_t-t\phi_{1}(u)} \tag 1
$$
is a positive Martingale wrt to $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(X_s:s\leq t)$. We can define a measure $Q$ under which $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is again a Levy process and its density on $\mathcal{F}_t$ is given by
$$
\frac{dQ}{dP}|_{\mathcal{F}_t}=Z_{t} 
$$

Now however the restriction of $dQ/dP$ on $\mathcal{F}_t$ first says that $Z_t$ is an $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable function and can be expressed almost surely as an function of the sample path $(X_s)_{s\leq t}$. Like in sequential statistics, we observe on $[0,t]$ and the induced likelihood-ratio depends on the process observed on this interval.

So i want an understanding how we get this expression of $Z_t$.
It would be nice to show that one has first can construct $Z_t$ in a common sense
$$
Z_{t}=e^{\int_{0}^{t}udX_s-\int_{0}^{t}\phi_{1}(u)ds} \tag 2
$$
which coincides with (1).

I want to show (2) or construct it.

We know that the induced measure of a path, is generated by its finite dimensional distributions.
Basawa "Statistical inference for Stochastic Processes" p. 181 recommends to calculate the finite dimensional distributions  of $X=(X_{t_0},X_{t_1},\ldots X_{t_n})$ for $0=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_n=t$ and let $\max_{1\leq i \leq n} t_i -t_{i-1}\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

For a sequece $K_{i}$ of independent random variables with finite mean we have with $S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}K_{i}$
$$
Z_n=\frac{e^{uS_n}}{E[e^{uS_n}]}
$$
Which is the classical sampling scheme.
Lets $(K_{1},\ldots,K_{n})=(X_{t_1}-X_0(=0),X_{t_2}-X_{t_1},\ldots,X_{t_n}-X_{t_{n-1}})$ the increments of the increments of the levy process.
Then
$$
Z_n=e^{(uS_{n})-t_1\phi_{1}(u)-(t_2-t_1)\phi_{1}(u)-\ldots (t_n-t_{n-1})\phi_{1}(u)}
$$
Letting $\max_{1\leq i \leq n} t_i -t_{i-1}\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ we can conclude (2).

But this is the law induced by the increments if i'm right. I need a connection of $(K_{1},\ldots,K_n)$ and  $X$ defined as above.